# XMPP Windows Phone 7 Library

Tags: windows-phone-7, xmpp

i want to build a IM client—with open standards access via XMPP 
i have download the argsXMPP SDK, and modify some classes which are not supported on windows phone 7
it have compiled successed,but it does not work. i finded some friends said argsXMPP have support windows phone 7 ,but i can not find the source code which is support windows  Phone 
so ,i am coming  here, i hope someone can  help me ,but my english is very poor,i dont sure whether anyone can understand my words ,please forgive me

if some have the souce code which can work on windows phone 7 well, i wa please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 2):

your friends are wrong. agsXMPP has no support for WP7. Only for the full .NET Framework and the Compact Framework. There are many missing classes in WP7 and the socket classes are totally different.

Comment: thanks. Are there other libraries can use on Windows Phone 7 ？

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [MatriX XMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/)?

Comment: thank you very much ,i have tried that,but the Matrix XMPP　SDK need momey . i do not have so much money to buy. thank you again

Comment: if anyone see this page ,please help me .thank you very much